# InDesign--show/hide layers of placed illustrator file based on variable

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, adobe-illustrator

I'm looking for a way to turn visibility on for various layers of an illustrator file based on variable data.

My initial forays suggest maybe this should occur within a script where the illustrator file is placed, rather than finding an existing file already placed on the page.

Basically, the scenario involved variable data—creating a pdf based on a two-page template for thousands of recipients, each recipient showing a map of the US with their state highlighted.

I'm thinking I'd place the variable in a header, then have the script find that variable, place the illustrator file, then make that state's layer visible—if the header includes "Hawaii" then the "Hawaii" layer would be made visible as the file was placed.

Possible?

I'm working out the first aspects—placing the image, finding the variable based on a labeled text box. Then I need to figure out the piece re: showing the layer in Illustrator.

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;   
doc.viewPreferences.rulerOrigin = RulerOrigin.pageOrigin;  
var _folder = Folder.selectDialog("Select a folder");  
var _files = _folder.getFiles();  
var myPages =doc.pages.length;

for(var i =0;i<_files.length;i++)  
{  

var stateLabel = "stateName",  
myPage = app.properties.activeWindow && app.activeWindow.activePage,  
myTextFrames = myPage.textFrames.everyItem().getElements().slice(0),  
l = myTextFrames.length,  
myVariable  

while (l--) {  
if (myTextFrames[l].label != stateLabel) continue;  
myVariable = myTextFrames[l].contents;  
break; 
}  

if(myVariable == "CA")
{  
    alert("california");  
    function FindOCG(StateDestinationMap) {
        this.layers["CA"].visible = true;
    };
} 
else(myVariable == "MN")
{
    alert("minnesota");
}
```

}

Comment: I think the part I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around is whether or not I'm able to check the map on each page (my test document has a US map with California and Minnesota. eventually I'll build in all 50 states).

The goal is to check a text box on the page (stateName) then make an OCG layer visible in the illustrator file on each page.

Comment: I don't think that InDesign has an object for layers in an Illustrator file. You may have to open the image in illustrator and show/hide the layer there, then update the link in InDesign. I believe this last part is scriptable. Another option would be to have 50 files, one for each state and have the script import the needed file as required.

Comment: It may be that I need to look at this a different way. Saving 50 illustrator files, looping through every page and placing the proper file on each page

Comment: Not sure to get you right but for what it's worth, InDesign can let an user edit layers visibility from a placed ai document to the condition the file was saved with layers. And yes, this can be set through scripting too. So given the variable value you can use the exact same source ai file but play with layers visibility for every placed instance.

Comment: Loic. In fact, that was my original plan, but I couldn't break through and figure out how to get there, so I ended up making multiple .ai files, instead of one layered file.